# How to sort a linked list using bubble-sort in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to implement Bubble sort for a linked list in JavaScript. I was looking for similar questions, but only found implementation in C ++ or Java. I would be grateful for your help. I have method which swap nodes and it works fine, but when I try to make loop it work wrong. Please help implement loop in right way.

LinkedListNode

```
export class LinkedListNode {
  public value;
  public prev;
  public next;

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}
```

LinkedList

```
import { LinkedListNode } from './LinkedListNode';

export class LinkedList {
  private head;
  private tail;

  addHeadNode = (value) => {
    const newLinkendListNode = new LinkedListNode(value);

    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    } else {
      this.head.prev = newLinkendListNode;
      newLinkendListNode.next = this.head;
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
    }
  };

  addTailNode = (value) => {
    const newLinkendListNode = new LinkedListNode(value);

    if (!this.tail) {
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newLinkendListNode;
      newLinkendListNode.prev = this.tail;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    }
  };

  getByIndex = index => {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (currentNode) {
      if (count === index) {
        console.log(currentNode);
        return currentNode;
      }
      count++;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return -1;
  };

  sort = () => {
    let currentHead = this.head;
    let length = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let newOne = new LinkedListNode(currentHead.value);
    if (
      currentHead.next !== null &&
      currentHead.value > currentHead.next.value
    ) {
      this.head = currentHead.next;
      this.head.prev = currentHead.prev;

      newOne.prev = this.head;
      newOne.next = this.head.next;

      this.head.next = newOne;
      console.log(this.head);
      currentHead = this.head;
      length++;
    }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: no one ever would use bubble sort, unless it is in a university environment. So, I recommend we help you instead of solving it for you.  
Where is the behavior not as expected? Maybe write a test for it / implement a code snippet here.

Comment: @Leviathan In a first loop it change nodes correctly but for the next one it doesn't change links for next and prev links correctly

Comment: @Leviathan adaptive sortings will choose an algorithm based on the size of the input to improve the performance. QuickSort has excellent time complexity but the fixed costs make it *slower* if you have, for example, 5 items only. For small inputs, a bubble sort vastly outperforms it despite being `O(n^2)`. Using `Array#sort()` in JS *does* sometimes use bubble sort. IIRC, it does it in Firefox if the input array has less than 10 items.

Comment: Why not add them to an array and reference the next and prev from the array?

Comment: @VLAZ i doubt that even for small lists, bubblesort is the fastest. There are way more algorithms than quicksort, I guess InsertionSort would be quicker than Bubblesort, even on a small size? I haven't touched this topic in a while, so.. but surely there is a better algorithm, even for small sample sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- Your loop never loops because the end condition is already false at the start:

  ```
  let length = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ```
- Bubble sort is an inplace sorting algorithm, so it should not involve copying node values into new nodes, like here:

  ```
  let newOne = new LinkedListNode(currentHead.value);
  ```

Here is how I would suggest implementing bubble sort with *singly* linked lists. You can extend it to *doubly* linked lists.

Of course, bubble sort is not very efficient, and doing it on a linked list is going to make it even slower:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, next=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {  // Allow input values like for Array constructor
        this.head = null;
        for (let value of values.reverse()) {
            this.head = new Node(value, this.head);
        }
    }
    
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {  // Can be used for looping & spreading
        let node = this.head;
        while (node) {
            yield node.value;
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    
    bubbleSort() {
        let sentinel = new Node(0, this.head);
        
        let dirty = true;
        while (dirty) {
            dirty = false;
            let node = sentinel;
            while (node.next && node.next.next) {
                let first = node.next;
                let second = first.next;
                if (first.value > second.value) { // swap
                    node.next = second;
                    first.next = second.next;
                    second.next = first;
                    dirty = true;
                }
                node = node.next;
            }
        }
        
        this.head = sentinel.next;
    }
}

// Demo
let list = new LinkedList(3, 7, 6, 9, 2, 5, 4, 8, 1, 0);
console.log(...list);
list.bubbleSort();
console.log(...list);
```